# Can't run program after set path as environment variable

Tags: batch-file, msbuild

I have set a new environment variable pointing to msbuild.exe folder.

```
C:\temp\Test>echo %DOT_NET4%

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
```

Now, if I start a new cmd and run "msbuild.exe", the programs runs ok, but after running this simple bat, the program is not found anymore:

```
"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svn.exe" checkout %CHECKOUT% %PATH%
cd %PATH%
nuget restore OpenText.sln
msbuild.exe OpenText.sln
```

> msbuild not recognized as an internal or external command.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @Sean83 Yes, I'm trying to create a build script, but it can't find the executables needed.

Comment: Are you omitting a key piece of that batch file? Because you're using the environment variable `PATH` there (which has a defined meaning) in a way that isn't really compatible with that meaning. However, I'm missing the part where you set `PATH`. Without you changing `PATH` I cannot see how what you describe is possible.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, where are you setting the msbuild path? To resolve your issues, please check if you have followed this process:

1. Open your system control panel, check for advanced system settings.
2. Click on Environment variables and edit PATH
3. Add a semicolon followed by the msbuild path.
4. Open a new command prompt and check if it is working or not.
5. Please note if you set msbuild in one command prompt, it will not be available in another command prompt.
6. Another issue which I see when I look at your logic is, you are trying to cd to %PATH% which should be avoided, you are either resetting the Environment variable path to a new path and trying to cd to it or you will land up file name longer issues, please use another variable instead.
7. In the bat which you are invoking, add a condition at the root level, such that if msbuild is not found, basing on  %ERRORLEVEL%, try adding msbuild to path again at batch level, so that you build will proceed.

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same thing as Joey in his comment. Your use of `CD %PATH%` is a red flag that indicates a problem.

`PATH` is a critical environment variable that contains a delimited list of folder paths where important executables are located. The command processor uses that list to locate programs when an external command is issued without the full path to the command.

If PATH is set correctly, then your command `CD %PATH%` cannot work. But I suspect you have some script that defines PATH to a specific folder, perhaps where nuget is located. In this case, your `CD %PATH%` command works, but now cmd.exe has no idea where msbuild.exe is located.

Moral of the story - don't ever use PATH for your own purposes. Pick some other variable name that is not reserved.